# Installing Google Earth ribbon tab in Erdas?

Tags: installation, google-earth, erdas-imagine

I have Erdas Imagine 11 and Google Earth installed, however the Erdas interface does not show the Google Earth ribbon tab.  I've tried re-installing both software packages, but the toolbox does not show up.

Comment: Have you spoken to anyone at Hexagon. I would think it is unlikely that anyone can help you based on such information.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Open GE
2. Open Erdas
3. In Help tab of Erdas type google in search commands box
4. You must see GE Icons.